# Purely Laravel: I would like to generate a key (token) on the page and then tell users to insert the key in a form in order to process the form

Tags: laravel

**Who is asking?** - Question is coming from less than 6 months old PHP developer who fell completely in love with PHP due to its awesomeness, also **I just joined STACKOVERFLOW today 7th Dec, 2019**.

**Reason for the question:** I have a form which I have completely built and validated with Laravel but I want to protect it from spam not with recaptcha but with a pin (a kind of generated key). I've seen it used on various websites and I also want to apply it.

**Plan of action:** The generated code will be placed at the end of the form with an input field and on filling it, it must match the code generated on every page refresh. If it doesn't match, I want to kill the page or perhaps, display a page with a "WELL DONE" message.

**My thoughts:** I'm new here and maybe the question might have been asked before, but honestly I've been on the computer for over a week (spending at least 18 hours searching and searching) but no really understandable solution.

**What I can't do:** Because I'm using Laravel, I don't know where to start this functionality and how to end it.

**My helper:** You are reading this and I believe you have the **skills and techniques** to help me without sweating at all. Just imagine a friend whose head is floating but the body is already in the ocean and about to drown. Also imagine a friend who has **only one shot (2 days) to change his life**, and if not done, only God knows what's to come. **PLEASE HELP ME!**

**To everyone:** Forgive me for the long message, I just believe that if I can express myself deeply enough, someone out there will help me out.

**Thank you to all the awesome developers around the world.**

Comment: the code you have seed probably is a csrf token, or maybe a hidden recaptcha

Comment: sounds like a recaptcha ... generate a random string, throw it in the session, have the view show this string, after submit check that field against what you put in the session

Comment: @ AlbertoSinigaglia and @ lagbox, your ideas are really great. I'll try both ways and see the one that does the job with lesser code. Thank you very much for being very supportive.